Is there a markup for word boundaries in HTML?
In short, when you look at:
<p>Hello</p><p>World</p>

You see (in markup) two paragraphs. I am looking for its counterpart for delimiting/enclosing words.
I looked through all HTML tags but I don't see anything relevant, and worse even if I abuse existing tags like div I don't get expected effect. So the question is -- is there such markup?
What I would like to achieve:

having words on a page, one after another, no spaces (in sense of character) between,
words should be recognized by browser as separate words, so double click on any of them should select given word, not entire sequence,
the solution should not force multiple lines in output (like raw div).

Of course I would prefer a tag which semantically describes the notion of "word", but as I see my chances are slim.
As for div I tried styling it to inline mode, but then Firefox treats all words as one entity, and double click selects them all.

span?

@KenzoStaelens I think the key here is the behavior around double clicking sibling elements without spaces.  So <span>foo</span><span>bar</span> looks like "foobar" and double clicking it selects the entire word despite it being 2 separate elements.  I think OP wants only one selected and I'm not sure of a way to do that without going through selection API on click.

Hello<span> </span>World and style the space in between to have font size 0

@zero298 ah sorry, i didn't know span selects them all together like that

@GuyIncognito, thank you, but I cannot add extra characters. So it has to be strict in the input sense (HTML markup) and also in output (what is displayed as page). Compare it to my example with p tag -- you can have them in the same line in markup, without any spaces between, and still they will be treated as separate paragraphs in display and behaviour.

Many recommended the use of the <span> tag. Actually, if you're interested in the "why" behind it, then the solution is to use the display: inline-block.


.inline-p > p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="inline-p">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>



Nevertheless, using a paragraph in this case is indeed misleading, as the two words together would constitute a single entity. Paragraphs imply the presence of distinct content. To maintain clean code, if the display truly consists of only two words, it's advisable to place them within a shared paragraph and apply a <span> within it.
If the goal is to keep the two texts completely separate as individual paragraphs with space between them, using display: flex seems the most straightforward to me. You can enable wrapping with the flex-wrap: wrap property. With the gap property, you can adjust the size of the space between them.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.25em;
}
<div class="container">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</div>




I believe this isn't what OP is looking for. Basically, "Hello World" should be displayed as HelloWorld but when double clicking it would only select the word you're clicking on - which would be "Hello" or "World". The markup would have distinct HTML tags, but on screen appear to be a single string.

Ah, I understand. Initially, I thought of using flex, but I hesitated because it would separate the text. However, if that's the goal, I'll add it.

Many thanks, this is 99% what I would like to achieve, but as @disinfor wrote (she/he is reading my mind) there is visual gap between words. "If the goal is to ... with space between them". It is actually in reverse -- visually there should be no space. In other words when reading you should not tell where the words (boundaries) are.
